# Get value from selected picker row in WatchKit 2

Tags: swift, watchkit, xcode7, watchos-2

I'm using Xcode 7 and I'm trying to pass a value from the picker to another function when a button is pressed. Is it possible to get the value of the row that is currently selected in the picker? Or do I have to use the picker as the button somehow? I tried implementing didSelectRow but when I try setting it up, I get an error: Use of undeclared type 'UIPicker View.' I'm guess I have to retrieve the index of the source array somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIKit` is not available for Apple Watch, and it is specially designed for iOS. Else you must use `WatchKit`.

In order to use user interface (`UI`) elements in your WatchKit App (watchOS1 or 2), you must use WatchKit (`WK`) elements instead, such as `WKInterfaceButton`.

So in order to have your app running successfully, replace `UIPicker` (which is an `UIKit` element) with `WKInterfacePicker` (which is a `WatchKit` element).

Note that `WKInterfacePicker` will only work in watchOS 2 (or later).

Comment: Does anybody know what the method is for getting the row index? I'm trying to google but can't seem to find it. I also have checked the apple documentation about wkinterfacepickers but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a UIKit class.

Use Watchkit classes with watch os 2:

```
WKInterfacePicker
```